# Jump or Jump over <something>

Tags: meaning-in-context, prepositions, ellipsis

"Jump over the turnstile" or "jump the turnstile".

I saw in a sentence "jump the turnstile."

Then I came to think whether it would be correct to say it like "jump over the turnstile".

Would that be correct?

Answer (score 10):

I think both would be fine. However, "jump over" usually carries a literal meaning, where you jump **over** a physical object (like a fence or a turnstile or a dog). On the other hand, "jump" without a preposition usually implies a non-literal meaning: "jump the queue" would mean skipping the queue in some way - no physical jumping involved. Likewise, your phrase of "jumping over the turnstile" could imply actually jumping over the turnstile barrier, or it could be "jump the turnstile" meaning "finding a way to avoid going through the turnstile" (and not paying/not having a ticket).

Answer (score 1):

You can say "to jump over the fence" and you can drop the preposition and say "to jump the fence".
It many cases verbs + preposition + noun can be shortened and used as transitive verbs, simply by dropping the preposition. 
But you are always correct if you use the preposition.

http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/jump_1?q=jump